# UI is not coming properly in actual device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

In my project, I am using two tabs and each tab has a fragment. It's looking good on emulator but it's not coming properly on actual android device. I want everything to fit in the screen properly, whatever is the resolution or size of the device. This is the just the fragment of one tab:

**fragment_encode.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/load_image_layout_margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loadImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/load_image_encode"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_upload_image"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageTextMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_open_image"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/description_upload_image"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:hint="@string/password_edit_text_hint"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textToEncodeButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56sp"
            android:layout_margin="12sp"
            android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground"
            android:text="@string/enter_text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/encodeButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
            android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground"
            android:onClick="decodeButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/encode"
            android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the snapshot of the device, where encode button is going down and not visible properly.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the button height to `wrap_content`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but not much change in button size. Can I make it responsive somehow? Ok I will try `wrap_content `.

Comment: Since you are using Linear Layout, I recommend to use the `layout_weight` attribute(of buttons, set 1 for each) instead of setting the views' `layout_height` specifically.

Comment: @Moon `layout_weight` is not working but `wrap_content ` worked well. Still I am thinking if I run my app on another phone with different size or resolution, it might be screwed.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the height of the buttons specifically is not recommended when it is possible for the views to go beyond the screen size. You can set the buttons' `android_height` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linear Layout with weights then it is recommended to use

```
layout_heigth="0dp"
layout_weight="1"
```

Only set the the height for the parent and not for the child views.
Try the following code, might be of help.
Adjust the weight for editText if current "1" doesn't work (use a value less than 1).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/load_image_layout_margin_top"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loadImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/load_image_encode"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_upload_image"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageTextMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_open_image"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/description_upload_image"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<EditText android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:gravity="left"
android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
android:hint="@string/password_edit_text_hint"
android:maxLength="16"
android:inputType="textPassword" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textToEncodeButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56sp"
    android:layout_margin="12sp"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground"
    android:text="@string/enter_text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/encodeButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground"
    android:onClick="decodeButtonClicked"
    android:text="@string/encode"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

If needed change the weights for the Linear Layouts and maintain the weight sum to be 1 or 100. Linear Layout will adjust themselves according to all screens.